# Data Execution Prevention: OptIn in a x86 OS

Tags: windows, dep

I would like to know, if anyone knows it, whether a service launched with the local System Account (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) and with the OS having configured the DEP in OptIn mode, will it run under DEP enforcement?

The OptIn option says literally (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352):
This setting is the default configuration. On systems with processors that can implement hardware-enforced DEP, DEP is enabled by default for ***limited system binaries and programs*** that "opt-in." With this option, ***only Windows system binaries*** are covered by DEP by default.

NXCompat Flag in the executable is 0.

Are processes launched by the SYSTEM account covered? Or are only the ones from system32 folder covered?

Thanks,
Simone

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Processes launched by the SYSTEM account are also covered by DEP, if they Opted-in (by having the [/NXCompat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235442%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in their image file). See Process Explorer below showing several services running with the SYSTEM account using DEP.[image]